# How to display body under the AppBar of scaffold widget and not below?

Tags: flutter

I'm using a transparent AppBar and I would like to display body behind the transparent AppBar and not bellow.
How to do that ?

Comment: How about using Stack, not using Scaffold?

Comment: As @najeira mentioned, Scaffold will not help you for this. Use Stack and make background of appbar transparent.

Comment: Your solution with a stack is correct but does not work if i try to add a form with TextField. Error No Material widget found.
TextField widgets require a Material widget ancestor.

Comment: Wrap Stack by Material.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

The parameter `extendBodyBehindAppBar` extend the body to include the height of the `AppBar`, if specified. [Scaffold](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html#extendBodyBehindAppBar) from Flutter.

```
Scaffold(
    extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
)
```

Available in Flutter stable 1.12+

### Feb, 2023 update

This will make the `AppBar` transparent, but you won't be able to tap on the `tappable` widgets in the body. For that you have to use `forceMaterialTransparency` parameter of AppBar.

```
AppBar(
      forceMaterialTransparency: true,
...
)
```

Comment: Thanks, With ListView it worked on setting the top padding to 0. `ListView(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0) `

Comment: GridView  requires the same thing: `GridView(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0))`

Comment: And then:  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent

Answer (score 67):

To place the body under the **AppBar** and make the [AppBar](https://flutter.io/docs/catalog/samples/basic-app-bar) transparent requires a **Stack** as the body. The [Stack](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) must contain the AppBar not the scaffold.

```
body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[...]
),
```

The first item in the stack is at the bottom and subsequent items are above it. If the AppBar is transparent it will appear to be working, but it is not. Making the AppBar green will show you why.

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          AppBar(title: Text('Hello world'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          )
        ],);
```

As you can see the AppBar takes up the entire screen and will consume any touch events.

[image: Full Screen App Bar]

To fix this use a [Position Widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html),

```
body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          new Positioned(
          top: 0.0,
          left: 0.0,
          right: 0.0,
          child: AppBar(title: Text('Hello world'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          ),),
        ], )
```

And you will get this:

[image: App Bar fixed]

Ok now make the AppBar transparent and remove the shadow:

```
body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container( //My container or any other widget
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          new Positioned( //Place it at the top, and not use the entire screen
          top: 0.0,
          left: 0.0,
          right: 0.0,
          child: AppBar(title: Text('Hello world'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, //No more green
            elevation: 0.0, //Shadow gone
          ),),
        ], )
```

[image: Transparent App Bar with full screen container below]

Hope this helps...

Comment: I want to make Appbar transcluent and with proper height, height should be same as Normal Appbar. I want to make Appbar Transcluent and some Background Color with Alpha. Is that possible ?

Comment: @SagarPanwala set the background to any color you want and then use the .withOpacity method to set the alpha value. i.e. Color(0xFF00FF77).withOpacity(0.5) see the help https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color/withOpacity.html

Comment: I mean to say Transcluent Appbar with Color(0xFF00FF77).withOpacity(0.5) to AppBar. If I give this color to AppBar, user can feel the strange height of AppBar which we can see in your answer. AppBar Height is quite big.

Comment: The last one is the one that worked with me, I didn't need to put it at the bottom of the stack

Answer (score 9):

Remove *appBar* from Scaffold
and just set Stack Widget in *body* and then wrap AppBar as last widget in Positioned widget.

> Note : Other answers are correct. But this posted because if anyone want gradient AppBar background and floating Card above it. :)

[image]

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
   body: setUserForm()
    );
  }

  Widget setUserForm() {
    return Stack(children: <Widget>[
    // Background with gradient
      Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  colors: [Colors.red[900], Colors.blue[700]])),
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3
        ),
    //Above card
      Card(
          elevation: 20.0,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 100.0),
          child: ListView(
              padding:
              EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 20.0, right: 18.0, bottom: 5.0),
              children: <Widget>[
                TextField(),
                TextField()
              ]

        )),
      // Positioned to take only AppBar size 
      Positioned( 
        top: 0.0,
        left: 0.0,
        right: 0.0,
        child: AppBar(        // Add AppBar here only
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0.0,
          title: Text("Doctor Form"),
        ),
      ),

    ]);
  }
```

Comment: TextField and TextFormField  focus not working with this code , any idea!

Comment: Could you please post TextField style also..?

Answer (score 5):

##### Screenshot:

[image]

##### Code:

If you want to take up entire space by making your `AppBar` transparent, you should also set `shadowColor` to a transparent color.

```dart
Scaffold(
  extendBodyBehindAppBar: true, // <-- Set this
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, // <-- this
    shadowColor: Colors.transparent, // <-- and this
  ),
  body: Placeholder(color: Colors.red),
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using this code

```
return new Scaffold(
  body: new Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Container(
        color: Colors.blue.shade200,
      ),
      new AppBar(
        title: new Text("App bar"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      new Positioned(
        top: 80.0,
        left: 0.0,
        bottom: 0.0,
        right: 0.0,
        //here the body
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

[image: Exemplo]

Answer (score 1):

A new option `extendBodyBehindAppBar` is now available on the Scaffold. See the [PR here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/39156).

If it's still an unrecognized parameter, make sure you switch to the `dev` channel and `flutter upgrade`.

Edit:
It's now on stable channel

Answer (score 0):

After some time I do not know if this will help anyone but...there it goes..

Problem: I wanted to have **gradient background** on the body of my `Scaffold`, and in Android the `AppBar` was messing things up.

My solution:

```
Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        title:  Text("AppBar text"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              colors: [
                HexColor.hexToColor("D76984"),
                HexColor.hexToColor("2369C0")
              ]),
        ),
      )
    );
```

Other solutions using `Stack` also might work but then the entire design of this screen is forced to use Stack which for me is less responsive than using other widgets...but that is just me.

Answer (score 0):

To extend the scaffold body behind the top AppBar, add this to your scaffold:

```
extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
```

To extend the scaffold body behind the [BottomNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html) or [BottomAppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomAppBar-class.html) (which would improve the UI's appearance when you have a docked FloatingActionButton), add this to your scaffold:

```
extendBody: true,
```

[image]

As you can see in my example, this causes the body to extend to the very bottom of the screen so you'll need to make sure you add spacing so the BottomAppBar doesn't hide UI features.