# How to get simple text on screen without Scafflod in Flutter?

Tags: android-emulator, dart, flutter, scaffolding

I have cleaned Flutter example from Scafflod and button and was expecting I get the same content, but without title bar and button:

```
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'My app title',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            new Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );

  }
}
```

Unfortunately, what I got is not fit any gates:

[image]

What is it? How it happen to turn so big? How to fix?

Comment: Probably a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50137939/how-to-use-drawer-in-flutter-without-scaffold

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Scaffold` is setting the basic material design visual layout structure, which much include default text styles, etc. If you don't want to use `Scaffold` for whatever reason, then you can apply the relevant text styles and colours from the current theme using `Theme.of(context)`. For example:

```
Text(
  'You have pushed the button this many times:',
  style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline,
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
),
```

Comment: Should I write this for any `Text` element? Is there any inheritance as in HTML?

Comment: You can use the `DefaultTextStyle` widget to define the base text style that you'd like to use, then any descendant `Text` element will use that style.

Answer (score 7):

You can wrap the text inside "Material" widget. Also, using "style:" parameter fixes the problem.

```
Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: Text(
            "Your Text Here",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'custom font', // remove this if don't have custom font
              fontSize: 20.0, // text size
              color: Colors.white, // text color
            ),
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Text(
  'Sign in / Sign up with',
  style: TextStyle(
    fontFamily: appFontFamily,
    fontSize: 20,
    decoration: TextDecoration.none,////set decoration to .none
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    color: defaultTitleColor,
  ),
)
```